# How to make editable PDF fields in a Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Is there a way to export a Jasper report in PDF where designated fields can be left editable? I'm using iReport to design the report templates.

Comment: As far as i know it's not possible....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible today. It's an unusual requirement, but it's not unreasonable. It's really not an iReport limitation but rather a JasperReports limitation. If anyone coming to this post in the future would like to have this feature, the best thing to do would be to log it in the [Jaspersoft bug tracker](http://community.jaspersoft.com/bug-tracker).

Comment: My answer was useful when written (more than 9 years ago!). But @yglodt's answer is better now. If Eric Hydrick is around, he should switch to accepting the newer answer.

Answer (score 8):

Editable inputs are possible with newer releases of `JasperReports`.

Example:

```
<reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="250" y="0" width="200" height="50">
  <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.field.type" value="Text"/>
  <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.field.text.multiline" value="true"/>
  <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
  <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.field.value">"This\nis a multi\nline text inside a single line text field."</propertyExpression>
</reportElement>
```

Documentation:

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/forms/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Two facts:

1. iText can do it.
   http://www.geek-tutorials.com/java/itext/itext_acroform_javascript.php#code2src
2. JasperReports use iText.

Theoretically, JR can do it, but I don't find methods in javadoc, that used parameters.

Maybe anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't but technically it is not impossible.
AFAIK,PDF editable field is specific to PDF format itself, JasperReport API is meant to produce only the commons elements to the major files format like text, tables, shapes, images...
The best way to find out the tip, is trying with input text for html format, you know you can have html elements in the jrxml. PDF also support html elements isn't it ?

Comment: Interesting idea, but using the <html> tag causes errors trying to view the report in design view.

Answer (score 0):

Added a "net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.isInputForm" to switch text field and static text component to pdf form text fields. Just set this property to "true" on static text or text field. The fix is just using itext's form within jasperreports.

https://github.com/ozawa-hi/jasperreports/tree/input_text