# Is it possible to generate PDF using jasper-reports with text field that can be filled in for printing?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make editable PDF fields in a Jasper report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870145/how-to-make-editable-pdf-fields-in-a-jasper-report)

I create my report using iReport and generate it using jasper-reports.

I would like to make a PDF report with text field that user can fill in, and print the edited document.

Can it be done, and how?

Comment: @AlexK, It's almost a 1 year old answer, maybe someone has come up with a solution during this time